Обработчик ошибок в aiogram
В 2 версии aiogram был обработчик ошибок, error_handler, в 3 версии он тоже есть но в документации приведен непонятный мне пример его использования. Мне нужен нормальный пример его кода, а не тот отрывок из документации. Если у кого  то есть, отправьте пожалуйста)
В интернете искал но не нашел информацию по этому поводу. Были посты или гайды но на вторую версию aiogram, когда мне нужна третья.

а в чем заключается вопрос?

@Алексей В 2 версии aiogram был обработчик ошибок, error_handler, в 3 версии он тоже есть но в документации приведен непонятный мне пример его использования. Мне нужен нормальный пример его кода, а не тот отрывок из документации. Надеюсь вы поняли меня)

Ну покажите пример из документации. Может он просто в разъяснении нуждается.

@CrazyElf Да пожалуйста,  ссылка

Так, и что там непонятного? Первый пример там - для вашего личного типа исключения, которое вы будете где-то в коде выкидывать. Второй пример - универсальный, для остальных типов исключений, которые не были пойманы в try/except в обработчиках.

На самом деле я пытался как то использовать этот код,  но у меня вылезала ошибка name 'MyCustomException' is not defined

Я незнаю где его взять

Ну потому что первый пример - это на случай, если у вас есть свой тип исключения MyCustomException, который вы описали в своём коде и выбрасываете там где-то сами опять же. Если вам не нужны свои какие-то типы исключений, то используйте второй пример. Если же нужны, то просто создайте класс class MyCustomException(Exception): pass и потом делайте raise MyCustomException где вам нужно.

Аааа.. Все я понял, спасибо
